# Android: Bind data to a ListView without preparing ArrayLists for the ListAdapter?

Tags: android, listactivity, listadapter, android-listview, expandablelistadapter

Right now, I get my Models in a nice object-oriented form. In order to bind them to my List, I have to use the listAdapter. Can I only fill this listAdapter with stupid ArrayLists? Because that means, I have to iterate over my ModelCollection and pull all the data out of my Models again.

So, I detach my data from the models and I cant easily refresh the data in my listView, if something chances in the modelCollection (like becoming bigger through new Items / pagination).

Does a more intelligent way exist, than I use right now? Can I bind my ModelCollection more driectly to the listView?

```
    ModelCollection modelCollection = ModelCategory.findAll();

    /*
     * Prepare Data for Adapter
     */
    ArrayList<String> itemTitles = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Iterate over my ModelCollection and pull all the Data from each Model
    for (int i = 0; i < modelCollection.items.size(); i++) {

      if (modelCollection.items.get(i) != null) {

        // TODO: Cant I bind my Models directly to the List without creating this ArrayList? 
        itemTitles.add(((ModelCategory) modelCollection.items.get(i)).getTitle());       

      }
    }

    /*
     * Create Adapter and bind Array
     */
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemTitles  );
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

One more question aside: How do I have to extend my code, when I want to add small subtitles underneath the title to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does a more intelligent way exist, than I use right now?

Write your own custom `ListAdapter` implementation, perhaps extending `BaseAdapter`, that works with your existing collection.

> One more question aside: How do I have to extend my code, when I want to add small subtitles
>   underneath the title to the list?

Your `getView()` in your custom `ListAdapter` implementation can format your rows however you wish, including using multiple pieces of data.

Comment: I recommend this tuturial: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/